# How can I change type attribute from submit to button on vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try like this:

```
<template>
    <button @click="checkout" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" :type="typeButton">
        Checkout
    </button> 
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            data() {
                return {
                    typeButton: 'submit'
                }
            },
            checkout(e) {
                this.typeButton = 'button'
                ...
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Which gives the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "typeButton" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
>   data properties in the data option.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `data(){}` object out of your `methods: {}`

So, your `export` should look like this:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      typeButton: 'submit'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkout(e) {
      this.typeButton = 'button'
    }
  },
}
```